Extract parts from sql sentences with pyhton script
I have a .sql file with CREATE TABLE AND INSERTS TABLE sentences in it.
Example:
INSERT INTO `examle` (`myid`, `title`, `value`, `usefull`, `picture`, `short_description`, `description`, `wikipedia`, `category`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'Cat', '3,45', 'No', 'cat.jpg', 'A very useless domestic cat.', 'The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felines and felids, is a small carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. It has been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years and is currently the most popular pet in the world.', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat', 'Sport,Food,Creature', '2009-10-27 16:37:49'),
(3, 'Basketball', '9,45', 'Yes', 'basketball.jpg', 'A Baskeball sport utility.', 'Basketball is a team sport in which two teams of 5 players try to score points against one another by placing a ball through a 10 foot (3.048 m) high hoop (the goal) under organized rules. Basketball is one of the most popular and widely viewed sports in the world.', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball', 'Sport', '2009-10-27 16:36:39')

I have to do a migration of that data in a database with tables that have a different structure of the .sql ones.
My question is: how can I get all the inserts of the file and from each of them the columns and values separated? Each insert should be a dictionary in a list.
I tried to use a pyhton script using regex and split(', ') each line of the values, but as some field have "," it's difficult to get the values correctly split.

Add a tag for the dbms you're using.

How looks the database table schema?

The table where I have to import the .sql data, each insert of the INSERT INTO is a record in the table and it has a field that is saved as a dictionary in the database, where the key should be name of the column (in the insert of the sql file) and the value, the value that is defined in the insert.
I don't know if there is an easier way to migrate the data of the sql file to a table with that structure.

You could just insert into a temp table with the given columns, then write a second sql insert from the temp table to the final destination table.

can you share the sample output you are looking for? also in your example the rows starting with 1,3 are in new line?

Perhaps you might parse these statements with sqlparse

@samhita I want that each insert of the INSERT sentence is a dictionary where the keys are the name of the columns of the table and the values are his value that is defined in the insert, and each dict is inside a list. Yes that example is one of the multiple inserts that I have in the sql file.

@JonSG I also tried to use that tool, but didn't find the way to do it.

@topsail Okayy I will try to do it, thanks.

Anyways I would like to know if there is some way to do it with sqlparse or another tool.

phpMyAdmin isn't a database platform, presumably you're using either MySQL or MariaDB which are the two main database programs used with phpMyAdmin.

This is very brittle, but will give you a list of dictionaries for statements formatted like you have provided.
Given:
statement = """
INSERT INTO `examle` (`myid`, `title`, `value`, `usefull`, `picture`, `short_description`, `description`, `wikipedia`, `category`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'Cat', '3,45', 'No', 'cat.jpg', 'A very useless domestic cat.', 'The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felines and felids, is a small carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. It has been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years and is currently the most popular pet in the world.', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat', 'Sport,Food,Creature', '2009-10-27 16:37:49'),
(3, 'Basketball', '9,45', 'Yes', 'basketball.jpg', 'A Baskeball sport utility.', 'Basketball is a team sport in which two teams of 5 players try to score points against one another by placing a ball through a 10 foot (3.048 m) high hoop (the goal) under organized rules. Basketball is one of the most popular and widely viewed sports in the world.', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball', 'Sport', '2009-10-27 16:36:39')
""".strip().split("\n")

Then you can use the ast package to parse your statement like:
import ast

## -------------------------
## Assume the first line is the INSERT clause
## -------------------------
fieldnames = statement[0].replace("`", "'")
fieldnames = ast.literal_eval(" ".join(fieldnames.split(" ")[3:-1]))
## -------------------------

## -------------------------
## Assume remaining lines are data
## -------------------------
data = ast.literal_eval(" ".join(statement[1:]))
## -------------------------

## -------------------------
## Construct our desired result
## -------------------------
results = [dict(zip(fieldnames, row)) for row in data]
## -------------------------

you can see the results using the json package for formatting:
import json

print(json.dumps(results, indent = 4))

That should give you:
[
    {
        "myid": 1,
        "title": "Cat",
        "value": "3,45",
        "usefull": "No",
        "picture": "cat.jpg",
        "short_description": "A very useless domestic cat.",
        "description": "The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felines and felids, is 
a small carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. It has been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years and is currently the most popular pet in the world.",
        "wikipedia": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat",
        "category": "Sport,Food,Creature",
        "date": "2009-10-27 16:37:49"
    },
    {
        "myid": 3,
        "title": "Basketball",
        "value": "9,45",
        "usefull": "Yes",
        "picture": "basketball.jpg",
        "short_description": "A Baskeball sport utility.",
        "description": "Basketball is a team sport in which two teams of 5 players try to score points against one another by placing a ball through a 10 foot (3.048 m) high hoop (the goal) under organized rules. Basketball is one of the most popular and widely viewed sports in the world.",
        "wikipedia": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball",
        "category": "Sport",
        "date": "2009-10-27 16:36:39"
    }
]


Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful

As there are some inconsistency with the data structure, I have added manual processing steps to clean the data.
Handling commas inside quotes:
Values in SQL data (like description or category) might contain commas inside them. If we split by commas directly, we would incorrectly break the data into multiple values.We use a manual loop over the values_str to handle this.
inside_quotes is a flag that tracks whether we are inside a quoted value ('), and current_value accumulates characters of the current value.
We toggle inside_quotes whenever we encounter a quote ('). If we're outside quotes and encounter a comma (,), it indicates the end of the current value, so we add it to the values list.
import json

def parse_sql_inserts(sql_content):
    lines = sql_content.strip().split("\n")
    first_line = lines[0]
    
    # Extract columns from the first line by finding everything between `(` and `)`
    columns_part = first_line.split("(", 1)[1].split(")", 1)[0]
    columns = [col.strip().strip('`') for col in columns_part.split(",")]
  
    result = []
    
    # Iterate over the rest of the lines (data values)
    for line in lines[1:]:
        if line.strip().startswith("VALUES"):
            continue
        
        # Remove the parentheses surrounding the values and strip extra spaces
        values_str = line.strip().strip("()")
        
        # Split the values by commas, ensuring we correctly handle commas inside quotes
        values = []
        current_value = ""
        inside_quotes = False
        for char in values_str:
            if char == "'" and (len(current_value) == 0 or current_value[-1] != '\\'):
                inside_quotes = not inside_quotes  # toggle the state of inside_quotes
                current_value += char  # add the quote itself to the current value
            elif char == "," and not inside_quotes:
                # When we're not inside quotes, this is the end of a value
                values.append(current_value.strip().strip("'"))
                current_value = ""
            else:
                current_value += char
        if current_value:
            values.append(current_value.strip().strip("'"))  # add the last value
        
        # Ensure the number of values matches the number of columns (sanity check)
        if len(values) != len(columns):
            print(f"Warning: Skipping line with incorrect number of values: {line}")
            continue
        
        insert_dict = dict(zip(columns, values))
        result.append(insert_dict)
    
    return result

sql_content = """
INSERT INTO `examle` (`myid`, `title`, `value`, `usefull`, `picture`, `short_description`, `description`, `wikipedia`, `category`, `date`)
VALUES
(1, 'Cat', '3,45', 'No', 'cat.jpg', 'A very useless domestic cat.', 'The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felines and felids, is a small carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. It has been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years and is currently the most popular pet in the world.', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat', 'Sport,Food,Creature', '2009-10-27 16:37:49'),
(3, 'Basketball', '9,45', 'Yes', 'basketball.jpg', 'A Baskeball sport utility.', 'Basketball is a team sport in which two teams of 5 players try to score points against one another by placing a ball through a 10 foot (3.048 m) high hoop (the goal) under organized rules. Basketball is one of the most popular and widely viewed sports in the world.', 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball', 'Sport', '2009-10-27 16:36:39')
"""

inserts = parse_sql_inserts(sql_content)

json_output = json.dumps(inserts, indent=4)
print(json_output)

Output
[
    {
        "myid": "1",
        "title": "Cat",
        "value": "3,45",
        "usefull": "No",
        "picture": "cat.jpg",
        "short_description": "A very useless domestic cat.",
        "description": "The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felines and felids, is a small carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. It has been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years and is currently the most popular pet in the world.",
        "wikipedia": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat",
        "category": "Sport,Food,Creature",
        "date": "2009-10-27 16:37:49')"
    },
    {
        "myid": "3",
        "title": "Basketball",
        "value": "9,45",
        "usefull": "Yes",
        "picture": "basketball.jpg",
        "short_description": "A Baskeball sport utility.",
        "description": "Basketball is a team sport in which two teams of 5 players try to score points against one another by placing a ball through a 10 foot (3.048 m) high hoop (the goal) under organized rules. Basketball is one of the most popular and widely viewed sports in the world.",
        "wikipedia": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball",
        "category": "Sport",
        "date": "2009-10-27 16:36:39"
    }
]


Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful
